# How to show barchart or pie chart of users versus return in Codeigniter website admin dashboard

Tags: codeigniter, google-analytics, google-api

How to show users versus return analytics information in admin dashboard? like below image.

[image]

Comment: You can create a library to act as a wrapper around this **google api** https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client Are you using **composer** with Codeigniter? You can find a list of metrics and dimensions here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#cats=user

Comment: Yes I had used composer for some previous project but not in this project.

Comment: If you are not using composer you could try this library https://github.com/ronan-gloo/Codeigniter-Google-Analytics-library simply copy the library/ and /config files into your project and look at the controllers/ to see how it is implemented.

Comment: ok thank you @ Philip